# Sinatra: data hiding methods

Tags: ruby, email, heroku, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app that I deploy with the use of heroku and github. There is a form that I use to send e-mails, processed as follows:

```
post '/send' do 
Pony.mail(
  :to => "**my_email**",
  :from => "**my_email**",
  :body => "Hi",

  :via => :smtp,
  :via_options => { 
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
    :port                 => '25', 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
    :user_name            => '--**MY_USERNAME**--', 
    :password             => '--**MY_PASSWORD**--', 
    :authentication       => :plain
  })
end
```

and of course everyone can see my username and password from github. How do I hide my login details without the database?
In other people's code I keep on seeing this method:

```
ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
```

I read what sendgrid is and I don't think I need it for my app with one form.
Are there other options to hide my data from web and github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into setting up environment variables (you are on the right track).

See here how to set up environment variables on Heroku:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Once your environment variable (EMAIL_USERNAME) has been set, you can access it from your code using:

```
email_username = ENV['EMAIL_USERNAME']
email_password = ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
```